# show and hide icon in autocomplete input when user insert a value - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an autocomplete input when user is not enter any value I want to hide the icon (x) when user insert a value if the input length >= 1 I want the icon appear in input I did something but can not change the state where I do wrong anyone can help me about it. Note when I insert text to the input I can see that my userInput changing in react console whatever I type in there.

fas fa-times icon to appear when user insert a value if not insert default is hidden icon

return is below

```
return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="input-group">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Arama metni giriniz."
                    onChange={onChange}
                    onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
                    value={userInput}
                />
                <div className="input-group-append">
                    <i
                        style={searchIconStyle}
                        className="fas fa-search"
                    />
                    <i
                        style={clearIconStyle}
                        className="fas fa-times"
                        onClick={this.onClearClick}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            {optionList}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
```

state is below

```
 state = {
    activeOption: 0,
    filteredOptions: [],
    showOptions: false,
    userInput: '',
    clearInputIcon: false
};
```

and function is here

```
 showIcon = () => {
    const { userInput } = this.state;
    const inputLength = userInput.length;
    if (inputLength >= 1) {
        this.setState({ clearInputIcon: true })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render the icon conditionally in your render method, no need for another state:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div className="input-group">
            <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Arama metni giriniz."
                onChange={onChange}
                onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
                value={userInput}
            />
            <div className="input-group-append">
                <i
                    style={searchIconStyle}
                    className="fas fa-search"
                />
                {
                    userInput.length >= 1?
                    <i
                        style={clearIconStyle}
                        className="fas fa-times"
                        onClick={this.onClearClick}
                    />: null
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        {optionList}
    </React.Fragment>
);
```